# Удаление внутренних тегов в строке не затрагивая его содержимое

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Какое должно быть регулярное выражение, что бы в строке удалить тег не затрагивая при этом его содержимое

```
<p>Text<a href="">NBC</a></p> //В a могут быть разные атрибуты
```

На выходе должно получится

```
 <p>Text NBC</p>
```

Comment: Хочу уточнить, если тэг будет внутри комментария, его удалять ?  

    // <p>text</p>
    /* <p>text</p> */

Comment: Да. Можно весь комментарий удалять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При тексте с некоторыми ограничениями можно применить парсер самого браузера таким образом:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = HTML;
var text1 = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
```

Этот способ взят из этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5002618/1299307). Там же можно найти полный список ограничений.
А вот регулярные выражения из того вопроса мне не понравились, поэтому пришлось писать свое:

```
var regex= /<(?:[^"'>]+|(["'])(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[\s\S])*\1)*>/g;
var text2= HTML.replace(regex, "");
```

Как работают оба варианта можно посмотреть на [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/gwEvK/).

Comment: но мне надо, что тег <p> не удалялся

Comment: @Zow, то есть обратно как его вставить после удаления Вы не знаете ?

Answer (score 0):

[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) jquery. Мне кажется это то, что нужно

Comment: @MrFranke, не то.

Comment: надо регулярку сделать для replace()